# ajax function is not working in my JavaScript function function skip the ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

return without executing the ajax function

```
function weekData(){
    var weekCount={};

 $.ajax({
         url:"http://localhost:8080/getWeeeks",
         headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
     },
     type:"GET",
         dataType:"json",
         data:{},

         success:function(data){

             for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
             weekCount[i]=data[i];

             }   
             debugger
             return weekCount;       

         },

     });

     return weekCount ;            
    }
var circle = weekData();
```

Comment: when I am using the debugger that showing the function the jump to the last return weekcount statement without executing ajax function and after return, its comes to the ajax why this going on?

Answer (score 1):

<s>You need to add `error` method along with check request on server-side to make sure that your ajax call is working fine.</s>

```
error: function (request, status, error) {
    alert(request.responseText);
}
```

---

**Updated**

There are numerous way to get the result from ajax response

1. Use `async: false` to make ajax response in sync like below

```
   $.ajax({
         url:"http://localhost:8080/getWeeeks",
         headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
         },
         async: false // This setting make ajax response in sync.
         ...
// Note that: It's not a good approach because of its deprecation and stuck the page untill the request comes back.
```

2. Return promise then manipuplate the done function

```
function weekData() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/getWeeeks",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {}
    });
}

var weekCount = [];
weekData().done(function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        weekCount[i] = data[i];
    }
});
```

3. Use `callback function`

Comment: This is not the answer.

Just to make sure, request is made or not, console log is also sufficient.

Comment: I've just updated my answer, please take a look at (please  reclaim downvote if need) @Zeeshan Eqbal

Comment: Done with pleasure

Answer (score 0):

## SOLUTION:

> Ajax calls are asynchronous by nature and defaults to true.

**Two approaches may work for this:**

First use Shorthand Ajax function and store the result into weekCount

```
 var weekCount = $.get( "ttp://localhost:8080/getWeeeks", function( data ) {
  return data.your-object-name;
});
```

**Second Option**

use `setTimeOut()` function to ensure the request is completed.

then callback to store the response in **weekCount**;

Comment: From my point of view, Use `setTimeout` is not a good approach. It's called **cheat code**. check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60109127/9071943) to have a better understanding.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the data object from ajax call. There is no need to send any data object when the method type is 'GET'.

```
data:{}
```

Comment: hey thanks for your suggestion but the problem is still same, my problem is that the ajax part is executing after the method is return the null from the last return statement and the method c0me on ajax after the return statement